# Android : Crash on Graph Scroll

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I have developed one line chart in which I am entering one value according to system date and plot line chart using achartengine library.

I am facing crash issue when I enter values in by changing date in reverse order.
i.e if I enter value for 6th june 2014 then for 5th june 2014 and so on till 1st june.

Please help...

I got Arrayindex outof exception Like :

```
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at org.achartengine.util.IndexXYMap.getYByIndex(IndexXYMap.java:86)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at org.achartengine.model.XYSeries.getY(XYSeries.java:203)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.drawChartValuesText(XYChart.java:590)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.drawSeries(XYChart.java:534)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.draw(XYChart.java:311)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:168)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-06 15:06:35.634: E/AndroidRuntime(579):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is Code where I am trying to draw graph :

```
GraphicalView mChartView = null;
    try
        {
            int y = 0;
            length = 0;
            int days_in_month1 = 0;
            String strDaysSaved[] = null;
            strDaysSaved = getAge();
            XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

            XYSeriesRenderer TimeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            // TimeRenderer.setColor(getResources().getColor(color.holo_red_light));
            TimeRenderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            TimeRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
            TimeRenderer.setPointStrokeWidth(8.0f);
            TimeRenderer.setFillPoints(false);
            TimeRenderer.setLineWidth(5.0f);// Integer.parseInt(getResources().getString(R.string.lineSize)));
            TimeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);

            XYSeriesRenderer InnerCircle = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            ;
            InnerCircle.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pointcolor));
            InnerCircle.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
            InnerCircle.setPointStrokeWidth(8.0f);
            InnerCircle.setFillPoints(true);
            InnerCircle.setLineWidth(0.1f);

            renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

            if (strDaysSaved.length == 0)
                {
                    showEmptyGraph();
                }
            setMainRendererProperties();

            arrayxvalues = new ArrayList<String>();// dates
            arrayxvalues = db.getmonths("dateadded");// group of months

            ArrayList<String> arrayxvalues1 = new ArrayList<String>();// dates

            for (int k = 0; k < arrayxvalues.size(); k++)
                {
                    days_in_month1 = 0;
                    String month = formatDate("MMM", getCalendarFromString(arrayxvalues.get(k), "yyyy-MM-dd"));
                    int year = Integer.parseInt(formatDate("yyyy", getCalendarFromString(arrayxvalues.get(k), "yyyy-MM-dd")));
                    boolean isleapyear;
                    if ((year % 4 == 0) && year % 100 != 0)
                        {
                            isleapyear = true;
                        }
                    else if (year % 400 == 0)
                        {
                            isleapyear = true;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            isleapyear = false;
                        }
                    arrayxvalues1 = db
                            .getmooddatesbymont(formatDate("yyyy-MM", getCalendarFromString(arrayxvalues.get(k), "yyyy-MM-dd")));// gruop of months
                    int days_in_month = daysInMonth(
                            Integer.parseInt(formatDate("MM", getCalendarFromString(arrayxvalues.get(k), "yyyy-MM-dd"))), isleapyear);
                    String year1 = formatDate("yyyy", getCalendarFromString(arrayxvalues.get(k), "yyyy-MM-dd"));
                    for (int d = 0; d < days_in_month; d++)
                        {
                            length = length + 1;
                            renderer.addXTextLabel(length, d + 1 + "\n" + month); // formatDate("dd\nMMM", getCalendarFromString(arrayxvalues.get(k), "yyyy-MM-dd")));
                            lenghts.add(length);
                            labels.add(d + 1 + "-" + month + "-" + year1);
                            xlabels.add(d + 1 + "-" + month);
                        }
                    for (int lb = 0; lb < arrayxvalues1.size(); lb++)
                        {

                            for (y = 0; y < labels.size(); y++)
                                {
                                    String currlabl = formatDate("d-MMM", getCalendarFromString(arrayxvalues1.get(lb), "MM-dd"));// monthly label
                                    String dat = formatDate("d", getCalendarFromString(arrayxvalues1.get(lb), "MM-dd"));
                                    if (currlabl.equals(xlabels.get(y)))
                                        {

                                            int g1 = 0;// ,days=0;
                                            if (k != 0)
                                                {
                                                    year = Integer.parseInt(formatDate("yyyy",
                                                            getCalendarFromString(arrayxvalues.get(k), "yyyy-MM-dd")));
                                                    if ((year % 4 == 0) && year % 100 != 0)
                                                        {
                                                            isleapyear = true;
                                                        }
                                                    else if (year % 400 == 0)
                                                        {
                                                            isleapyear = true;
                                                        }
                                                    else
                                                        {
                                                            isleapyear = false;
                                                        }
                                                    g1 = g1 + Integer.parseInt(Mood.getString(findDays, "0"));
                                                    days_in_month1 = g1
                                                            + daysInMonth(
                                                                    Integer.parseInt(formatDate("MM",
                                                                            getCalendarFromString(arrayxvalues.get(k), "yyyy-MM-dd"))),
                                                                    isleapyear);
                                                    plotx.add(lenghts.get(g1 + Integer.parseInt(dat)));
                                                }
                                            else
                                                {
                                                    year = Integer.parseInt(formatDate("yyyy",
                                                            getCalendarFromString(arrayxvalues.get(0), "yyyy-MM-dd")));
                                                    if ((year % 4 == 0) && year % 100 != 0)
                                                        {
                                                            isleapyear = true;
                                                        }
                                                    else if (year % 400 == 0)
                                                        {
                                                            isleapyear = true;
                                                        }
                                                    else
                                                        {
                                                            isleapyear = false;
                                                        }
                                                    days_in_month1 = 0;
                                                    days_in_month1 = g1
                                                            + daysInMonth(
                                                                    Integer.parseInt(formatDate("MM",
                                                                            getCalendarFromString(arrayxvalues.get(0), "yyyy-MM-dd"))),
                                                                    isleapyear);
                                                    if (lenghts.size() == Integer.parseInt(dat))
                                                        plotx.add(lenghts.get(g1 + Integer.parseInt(dat) - 1) + 1);
                                                    else
                                                        plotx.add(lenghts.get(g1 + Integer.parseInt(dat)));
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = MoodDairy.edit();
                    editor1.putString(findDays, String.valueOf(days_in_month1));
                    editor1.commit();
                }
            renderer.setPanLimits(new double[]
                { 0, days_in_month1, 0, 8 });// [panMinimumX, panMaximumX, panMinimumY, panMaximumY]
            String firstdate = "";
            if (labels.size() != 0)
                {
                    firstdate = labels.get(0).toString();
                }

            String[] months = db.getmonthsmood();// 01-12
            if (!firstdate.equals(""))
                {
                    for (int h = 0; h < months.length; h++)
                        {
                            renderer.setPointSize(15f);
                            if (h == 0)
                                {
                                    dataset.addSeries(addSystolicUserSeries(months[h], h, ""));
                                    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(TimeRenderer);
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    dataset.addSeries(addSystolicUserSeries(months[h], h, months[h - 1]));
                                    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(TimeRenderer);
                                }
                        }
                }
            // To draw yellow circle inside
            if (!firstdate.equals(""))
                {
                    for (int h = 0; h < months.length; h++)
                        {
                            renderer.setPointSize(5f);
                            if (h == 0)
                                {
                                    dataset.addSeries(addSystolicUserSeries(months[h], h, ""));
                                    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(InnerCircle);
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    dataset.addSeries(addSystolicUserSeries(months[h], h, months[h - 1]));
                                    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(InnerCircle);
                                }
                        }
                }
            if (arrayxvalues.size() > 0)
                txtvwgraphtitle.setText(formatDate("MMMM yyyy", getCalendarFromString(arrayxvalues.get(0), "yyyy-MM-dd")));
            calculaterange();
            mChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, dataset, renderer, "");
            mChartView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                        {
                            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                        }
                });
        }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
        }
    catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    return mChartView;
```

Comment: Post your code where null exception happens!

Comment: @Zoran Please look @ edited code

Comment: Please find on which line happens error, because you have multiple for iterations and error happens inside one of them.

Comment: do you  have  this "IndexXYMap.java" class in your project??

Comment: @Mohit no i don't have such class.

Comment: @Zoran Actually I am in search of that exact line where it happens

Comment: ok user123 your exception is IndexOutOfBoundsException its means your array length is 3(0,1,2) and your for loop ,loop 4 times (0,1,2,3) thats a problem your array list size is 3 but you loop 4 , check items in arraylist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you so much for your interest in my question
I found solution on my problem
I had set this property :

```
XYSeriesRenderer TimeRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
TimeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
```

on removing TimeRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true); this line there is no crash happening.

Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am suspicious that error maybe happens at:

```
if (lenghts.size() == Integer.parseInt(dat))
    plotx.add(lenghts.get(g1 + Integer.parseInt(dat) - 1) + 1);
else
    plotx.add(lenghts.get(g1 + Integer.parseInt(dat)));
```

Check it please!

Comment: Thanks Zoran but it is not there I had put a debug point there